# Windows Azure VM Websocket port doesn't working

Tags: php, azure, websocket, virtual-machine, port

I have a PHP Websocket server, which working on port 9300.
Locally everything working fine, but remotely it doesn't work.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://**MyVM**.cloudapp.net:9300/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**I added the endpoint in Azure portal, and open inbound connection in Windows Firewall.**

What should I do?